# Oracle SQL: Pattern Matching with Sub-Strings

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables, TAB1 and TAB2.

In both tables there is a column that exhibits a concatenation of sub-strings. I would like to join the two tables based on these columns. However, while the sub-strings of TAB2 have to be present in TAB1 in the indicated order, other sub-strings can be pushed inbetween individual sub-strings.

Here is an example:

Imagine I have the following sub-string in TAB2:

```
A ; B ; C
```

I would like to have a join, whenever there is an A, followed up by an B, followed up by an C in TAB1's column - it does not matter when there are other sub-strings between A, B, C.

The join should be successful, for the following cases (TAB1' column shown):

```
A; A; B; C
A; C; B; C
D; E; A; D; B; C
```

It should be unsuccessful, whenever A is not followed up by an B is not followed up by an C. For instance:

```
A; B
C; A; B
A; C; B
D; E; A; C
```

Is there a fast and succesful solution for my problem. I would be very happy for any recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions.  Based on your sample data this should work:

```
from tab2 t2 join
     tab1 t1
     on regexp_like(t1.col, replace(t2.col, ';', ';|')
```

You might want to put semicolons at the beginning of both strings, especially if the strings might not be distinct.

Also, this is a lousy data structure.  It seems like you are storing multiple values in a single column.  That is not the best way to store data in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In the join condition, I use regexp_replace function to replace both spaces and semicolon by '%' character, then I pad both sides with that same character '%', then I use like operator to match all the desired rows from table1

```sql
select t1.col1--, t2.col2
from tab1 t1
join tab2 t2 on col1 like '%'||regexp_replace(t2.col2, '\s*;\s*', '%')||'%'
;
```